# Is there a way to check whether the given list is of numbers or not?

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to write scheme program to check whether the given list consists of numbers or not i.e if the input list is of numbers, program returns true.

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with my code

```
(define (is_num(lst))
(if (not (number? (car lst)))
    #f
(is_num(cdr lst))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(define (isnum lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) #t)
          ((number? (car lst)) (isnum (cdr lst)))
          (else #f)))
```

This will return `#t` if all the symboles a numbers `#f` if any symbole is not a number.
For exemple :

```
(isnum '(0 1 1 2)) ; will be #t
(isnum '(0 'a 1 2)) ; will be #f
```

You will need to read about [define](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html?q=define#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._define%29%29) ([in a nutshell](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/prog3-03/html/notes/fu-intr-1-note-fun-def.html)) and [conditions](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fletstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29) (I suggest `cond` in stead of `if`).

You need a [stopping condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination) otherwise you recursion will be infinite.